# How to check if array elements contain string?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, ecmascript-6

Trying to omit the element that contain string it is still returning `mailPrice` that contains `Not Covered` string , Any idea about the fix ?

data

```
const drug = {
  "isBrand": false,
  "drugName": "Atorvastatin Calcium",
  "drugStrength": "80mg",
  "drugForm": "Tablet",
  "mailPrice": {
    "totalQuantity": 90,
    "rejectMessage": [{
      "settlementCode": "99",
      "settlementDesc": "Not Covered Sorry, the system is temporarily:Lo sentimos,Intente(Código de error 85)"
    }]
  },
  "retailPrice": {
    "totalQuantity": 30,
    "rejectMessage": [{
      "settlementCode": "99",
      "settlementDesc": "Sorry, the system is temporarily:Lo sentimos,Intente(Código de error 85)"
    }]
  },
  "specialtyPrice": {}
};
```

main.js

```
const priceFilterHandler = (item) => {
  const retailHasCode = findErrCode(item.retailPrice && item.retailPrice.rejectMessage);
  const mailHasCode = findErrCode(item.mailPrice && item.mailPrice.rejectMessage);
  if (retailHasCode) {
    delete item.retailPrice;
  }

  if (mailHasCode) {
    delete item.mailPrice;
  }

  return item;
}


const findErrCode = (data) => data && data.some((item) =>

  item.settlementDesc.includes(!'Not Covered')
);

console.log(priceFilterHandler(drug));
```

expected output

mailPrice is omitted in below response because its rejectMessage contain string `Not Covered`

```
{
      "isBrand": false,
      "drugName": "Atorvastatin Calcium",
      "drugStrength": "80mg",
      "drugForm": "Tablet",
      "retailPrice": {
        "totalQuantity": 30,
        "rejectMessage": [{
          "settlementCode": "99",
          "settlementDesc": "Sorry, the system is temporarily:Lo sentimos,Intente(Código de error 85)"
        }]
      },
      "specialtyPrice": {}
    };
```

Comment: checkout `typeof` keyword you should be able to add a condition like `if(typeof val === 'string')`

Comment: You sure you want to check the rejectMessage includes that? and Not `settlementDesc` or something else?

Comment: @TKol so each element in rejectMessage will have settlementDesc we need to check if it contains `Not Covered` then returns true

Comment: @TKoL ok i have updated my question by checking `item.settlementDesc.includes(!'Not Covered')` it returns `mailPrice` as well it should not as i mentioned in expected output

Comment: `iitem.settlementDesc.includes(!'Not Covered')` there is a typo here

Comment: You have a typo here `iitem.settlementDesc.includes(!'Not Covered')` it should be `item.settlementDesc.includes('Not Covered')`

Comment: @CodeManiac this is weird it works opposite if i have `item.settlementDesc.includes('Not Covered')` its removing the mailPrice , does it make sense ?

Comment: @hussain you wanted to remove that in your expected output isn't it ?

Comment: @CodeManiac yes but in my understanding `item.settlementDesc.includes(!'Not Covered')`  should exlude the mailPrice not this `item.settlementDesc.includes('Not Covered')`

Comment: `item.settlementDesc.includes(!'Not Covered')` what are you trying with `!` here ? it changes value `Not covered` to false and you end up doing this `item.settlementDesc.includes(false)`

Comment: @CodeManiac ok make sense, Can we do this if we have to check another string `item.settlementDesc.includes('Not Covered' || 'Invalid Quantity')`

Comment: @hussain no you can this way it check only `Not covered`, you can use `search` then `item.settlementDesc.search(/Not Coverd|Invalid Quantity/)`

Comment: @CodeManiac its always returning `retailPrice` with search method you mentioned

Comment: @hussain you don't have any matching value in your `retailPrice`, you should read your question properly yourself

Comment: @CodeManiac yes i dont want to change the question now it will mislead but i am trying that in my code it is always returning `retailPrice`

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for this: https://jsfiddle.net/5cnqwfgu/1/

```
Object.entries(drug).forEach(entry => {
if(typeof entry[1] === "object") {
            if(entry[1]['rejectMessage'] && entry[1]['rejectMessage'].length > 0 && entry[1]['rejectMessage'][0]['settlementDesc'].includes('Not Covered')){
                delete drug[entry[0]];
        }
    }
});

console.log(drug);
```

Comment: @hussain..please accept if this solves your problem !